# Find $k$ sets with its elements where intersection of every two sets has cardinality 1

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have $k=30$ sets $S_i$ and each set contains $n=8$ elements. I have $v=36$ unique elements which can be in a set. For every two sets $i\neq j$  it shall be true that $|S_i \cap S_j|=1=a$. Is there an algorithm to compute an arbitrary combination of elements such that the condition holds (arbitrary because it should be invariant w.r.t. which exact elements I chose)? Also, I am unsure if the $v$ I found is correct, so possibly $v$ must be higher. Besides, I tagged the question as a graph problem, because I think you can view this problem from a graph theoretical point of view too. Thanks.

Comment: It’s certainly possible with $v=k=57=7^2+7+1,n=8$ just taking the projective plane of order $7,$ so $8$ points per line.

Comment: The question comes under the heading of "combinatorial designs," a topic in which there are some formulas but also a lot of instances where all you can do it hand it to a computer and grind away. There are tabulations of combinatorial designs on the web, you could try a websearch.

Comment: Thanks Gerry and Thomas! I actually found a nice Wiki Article (in German it's a bit more thorough but the illustration in the English one ist great): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobble

Comment: If you have found a solution, Marcel, let me encourage you to write it up & post it here as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea :) will do that in one of evening hours!